# C# if element not found, then something else

Tags: c#, linq

I have a simple table

[image]

Here's a snippet of my code.

```
var person = db.Person.Where(p => p.ID == inputId).Select(o => o.ID).FirstOrDefault();
```

return person;

inputId is a user input field. What I need is if the inputId is not in the table (eg. 5, 6, 7, ect), I want an if/else option to create a new user/reenter a correct id.

Thanks

Comment: So what are you waiting for?

Comment: Check if any exist then db.Person.Any(p => p.ID == inputId)

Comment: if person is null then that is your else statement

Comment: so you have heard of the `if/else` construct but do not know how to use it?

Comment: That's a verbose way to just check if an ID exists... also naming a variable person, but putting only an ID in it is a good way to confuse your fellow programmers ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [null-coalescing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) operator is one way

```
var person = db.Person.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == inputId) ?? new Person();
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you return the ID, not the person. To return a person, you should do this:

```
var person = db.Person.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == inputId);
```

As for the question, I would prefer this option:

```
if (db.Person.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == inputId) is Person person)
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first select record

```
var person = db.Person.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == inputId);
if(person == null) //check if not exist 
{
  //add
  db.Person.Add(PersonDetails);
  db.SaveChanges(); 
}
// else return person object 
return person;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check existence of record with `.Any()` method:

```
if(db.Person.Any(p => p.ID == inputID))
{
   return db.Person.First(p => p.ID == inputID);
}
else
{
   //Set user notification message
}
```